# What is the purpose of the 賣 (卖) component in the character 讀 (读)?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

Most sources I can find say that 讀 (读) is a phonosemantic compound (形聲), where 言 is the semantic component and 賣 is the phonetic component.

However, the pronunciation of 賣 (mài) does not resemble 讀 (dú) at all, even in Middle Chinese (賣 /mai/; 讀 /duk/) or Old Chinese (賣 /mreːs/; 讀 /l'oːɡ/).

What is the purpose of the 賣 component in the character 讀?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, 賣(u+8ce3) is sell; while (u+27da0) is pronounced as "育".

left is 賣(u+8ce3), right is (u+27da0), note the difference of the middle component:

[image: screenshot]

well, in the past, 賣(u+8ce3) is for 買賣 (buy & sell) only. other characters e.g., 讀, 贖, 覿, 續 are using (u+27da0).

[image]

so, 讀 as a phonosemantic compound character is, combined "言" & (u+27da0); that's why it's 屋韻﹒徒谷切

somewhere in time, the (u+27da0) is less used, and 賣 is more "popular"; which causes confusing.

Comment: Are there any clues to what  means, or is it only seen as a component in other characters?

Comment: 說文解字 explained (u+27da0)﹒ 衒也; that  = 衒; and, 衒 is (same, from 說文解字) 行且賣也 (~ peddle, selling goods from place to place). in summary,  (u+27da0) means peddle, roughly.

Answer (score 1):

"賣" / mai4 / and ""/du2/ have different sound

瀆 as in 自瀆      /du2/

犢 as in 初生之犢 /du4/

讀 as in 讀書 /du2/

they are all phonically similar

from http://www.shuowen.org/view/1489

> 从言。聲。

from http://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&char=%F0%A7%B6%A0&remap=gb

> 《康熙字典》.... 中从囧，非字也。

It said the middle of  is 囧, it is not the the word ""(sell) (I think it meant not the word "賣" )